# Gravity simulation for a ball

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm implementing this game that uses gravity, but I don't know how to simulate gravity for a ball.

I have a timer that starts right after I "drop" the ball and I have to set the vertical position of my object ball.

The related functions are:

```
int ball->setVerticalPosition(int Y);
float timer->getTime();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, in general, you would calculate the new position (pos_y) with this equation:

```
t = timer->getTime();
float pos_y = pos_y0 + v_0*t - 4.9 * t *t;
ball->setVerticalPosition(pos_y);
```

(v_0 is the initial velocity and pos_y0 the initial coordinates of your ball). In your case, you say you are 'dropping' de ball, so probably it's better if you remove the v_0*t. And pos_y0 is the original heigth (depends on your coordinate system).

Don't forget to check when pos_y=0 (your floor probably!)

Comment: I will try that right now and see whether it works... I doesn't look good...

Comment: Why 4.9? Gravity tend to be 9.8m/s.

Comment: To make it even more realistic, you'll need to simulate the air resistanse as well, or just cap the speed at some level (terminal velocity)

Comment: @dutt: Gravity is ~9.8 m/s^2, and the distance travelled when the acceleration a is constant is at^2/2; in this case 9.8*t^2/2 = 4.9 * t^2.

Answer (score 3):

I gave 4.9 because gravity is 9.8, and equation is "1/2*g*t*t", I just divided and gave the final number. This is in "meters", should convert to pixels for example.

Comment: Next time use a comment, or edit your previous answer...